# Unable to log into any accounts (regular or root)

Tags: macos, user-account, login, root

After starting up macOS Sierra, I am unable to log into any accounts (regular or root). I don't recall making any changes to system files or user accounts, so am generally puzzled by this.

Comment: Why do you have to periodically re-install macOS? - By choice? or because the system stops working?

Comment: Loads more info. For what purpose do you have root enabled and SIP disabled? What sort of files were you downloading today - executables? Can you clarify the two different methods you used to login?  Can you boot into Safe Mode? Any reason you're still on Sierra and not upgrading? The original loss of WIFI just sounds like you needed to reconnect to the network.

Comment: @jksoegaard the system sometimes stops launching apps properly (if at all), won't switch windows, has no dock, and similar problems

Comment: @benwiggy I have SIP disabled because I occasionally change things with the system that are protected (or have apps that do), and I have root enabled because... Uuuhhhh... I had a reason...

Comment: @benwiggy I remember now it's because I do some ssh stuff, so that way I can login to root and access everything (and modify/move/copy/delete stuff that I usually wouldn't be able to)

Comment: Also, @benwiggy I was downloading apps, I'm not upgrading to High Sierra because of how they changed how the file system, both are the same method I guess (I'm not sure), I tried reconnecting to three different networks but I had the same problem on all of them

Comment: APFS should not affect you one bit. Sounds like you're massively over-complicating your usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been that I accidentally added a tag (in Finder) to the root user's home directory (`/private/root). Removing it fixed the issue.